# Dict-like collection for attributes

Tags: python

Is there a class in Python 2.7 that behaves like:

```
x = AttrDict(foo=1, bar=2)
x.foo  -> 1
x.bar  -> 2
```

for arbitrary attributes / constructor keywords?

- A `dict` is close, but doesn't have attribute access <strike>nor such a nice constructor syntax</strike>.
- A named tuple comes close too, but I don't want to create a new type for each combination of attributes.

Something like that would be handy to have sometimes. I could make one myself in a minute, but it sounds like something that might exist in Python already.

Comment: Actually, `dict` *does* have such nice constructor syntax, try it: `dict(foo=1, bar=2)` -> `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}`. The crux is that keys are not attributes.

Comment: You just blew my mind. I've used dict sooo many times and have never noticed that. How embarrassing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.3, the standard solution is [`types.SimpleNamespace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace), but this is not backported to 2.7. A very similar type, [`argparse.Namespace`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) exists in 2.7. It's a little obscure but documented and hence okay to rely on.

Comment: It took me a while to understand that documentation :-) I think  someone reading my code, seeing argparse imported, would be rather confused. Still nice answer, I'd never found it.

Answer (score 2):

Going along with the subclassing solution, you could do something like this:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

It looks a little weird, but it should work. It takes advantage of the builtin attribute location for python objects `__dict__`

```
>>>x = AttrDict(foo=1, bar=2)
>>>x.foo  
1
>>>x.bar 
2
>>>x.baz = 3
>>>x.baz
3
>>>x.missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'AttrDict' object has no attribute 'missing'
```

Comment: I think you have to drop the `**` in front of `kwargs` when making the super call. At least that is my solution. *edit* I'm wrong... it works.

Comment: Sorry about that. It works without them as well: `.__init__(kwargs)`. Since `kwargs` is a dict too, that is simply using the copy-ctr. I wasn't using `*args` in my variant at all. I didn't know that dicts could be initialized with keywords. Yours is nicer without doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `dict` to do something like this:(Thanks to @delnan, two such objects are already available in standard library)

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        self.__setitem__(attr, val)
...         
>>> x = AttrDict(foo=1, bar=2)
>>> x.foo
1
>>> x.bar
2
>>> x.spam = 'eggs'
>>> x.spam
'eggs'
```

Comment: You are not *overriding* dict, you are sub-classing it.

Comment: @delnan Never heard of those, so a +1 to you.

Comment: I'm not sure whether subclassing `dict` is the best approach though: I know OP described it as such, but inheriting the `dict` functionality means several attribute names (`items`, `values`, and other common ones) are reserved/unavailable.

Comment: @delnan That's true, even `namedtuple` class has attributes that start with `_` to prevent such collisions.

Comment: @delnan: A simple fix would be to modify the snippet by Matthew to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma However, it's even simpler to just subclass `object` and do nothing special. The issue is not how to make arbitrary attributes work - you get that for free and have to actively prohibit it. The issue is whether you *want* the `dict` methods.